# wield boost_check results

Tags: unit-testing, boost, shared-ptr

the same boost_check command gives me different results in different files.

I have the same following code in three different files.

```
 boost_check ("bb" < "bbb" )  ;
```

While two of them pass, one of them failed.  the one that didn't pass associate with a class using boost::shared_ptr (v:1_41_0);

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: I figured out that it might relate to using boost shared_ptr (v:1_41_0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"bb" and "bbb" are of type `const char *`

When you compare them, you are comparing the pointers, not the strings.
Which one is less depends on lots of other things, determined at compile time.